# IRS SDK in .NET Can we use this into Node project

Tags: node.js, .net, irs

Hey there i am facing an issue to trying use the IRS SDK that are creating into the .NET and Jave.

my project is into the nodejs now i need to integrate the IRS form system into my project.

can any one help me to figure out how we get the right path.

Need to get the Path how we integrate the IRS into our system. we have alread the IRS sdk.

Comment: The obvious answer would be to create an ASP.NET API around the IRS SDK and call that from Node.